# strings inside python template- and f-strings

Tags: python

Could someone please break down why `"{dic['string_key']}".format(dic=dic)` considers the single quotations to be part of the string-key and does a lookup under `dic["'string_key'"]` ?

a) and b) show the correct way, however I am missing the reason.

```py
a = "{dic[string_key]}"
print(a.format(dic=dic))

b = f"{dic['string_key']}"
print(b)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post a [mre]  and show the output you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case:

```
a = "{dic[string_key]}"
print(a.format(dic=dic))
```

... the string is formatted when `.format()` is called and that function uses a formatting language that is documented here https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings.

But in this case:

```
b = f"{dic['string_key']}"
print(b)
```

... the string is formatted when the assignment to `b` is executed, by Python itself. The expression inside the f-string follows normal Python syntax, with the exception that you cannot reuse the quotes used to enclose the f-string.

As a result, you need to specify the quotes around the dictionary key as you would normally, while the mini-language for `.format()` expects you to omit them.

Also note that this makes a lot of sense: `b = f"{dic[string_key]}"` should use the value of the variable `string_key` to index the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

`format` and f-strings use braces differently.

With `str.format`, the contents of the braces are part of a mini-language used by `format` to substitute its arguments into the format string.

In an f-string, it's an arbitrary Python expression to evaluate.